# AWS user is not authorized to perform codepipeline:GetPipeline on resource because no identity-based policy allows the codepipeline:GetPipeline action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to execute  `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name pipeline` in order to fetch information about pipeline.

The result is this message:

> AWS user is not authorized to perform codepipeline:GetPipeline on resource because no identity-based policy allows the codepipeline:GetPipeline action

I checked my user and it has admin privileges (allow all actions and resources). Tried to add codepipeline:GetPipeline action to pipeline role as well, did not help.

Can you help me spot the issue?

Comment: Is your account perhaps part of an AWS organization?

Comment: @Paolo yes it is

Comment: I suspect there's an explicit deny for this action at a higher level; can you check that?

Comment: @Paolo Can you tell me how?

Comment: Do you have access to the AWS organization? Are you part of an OU (organizatonal unit)? If so, check whether the OU has a SCP policy attached to it

Comment: @Paolo It does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244803/discussion-between-paolo-and-pokemzok).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Paolo yeah. It was a couple of issues bundled, but the main was my account lacking that particular privilege. So your call was very close.